# find annotation pure text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have underlined a part of PDF text which appears in annotations. I succeed to locate the annotation, but how to return the corresponding pure text ? The annotation contains following fields:

```
-       Keys    Count = 12  Dictionary<PdfName,PdfObject>.KeyCollection
+       [0] {/C}    PdfName
+       [1] {/F}    PdfName
+       [2] {/M}    PdfName
+       [3] {/P}    PdfName
+       [4] {/T}    PdfName
+       [5] {/AP}   PdfName
+       [6] {/NM}   PdfName
+       [7] {/Rect} PdfName
+       [8] {/Subj} PdfName
+       [9] {/Subtype}  PdfName
+       [10]    {/QuadPoints}   PdfName
+       [11]    {/CreationDate} PdfName
```

I have tried to search correspondance between `'/NM'` value and `'reader.GetNamedDestinationFromNames()'` or `'reader.GetNamedDestinationFromStrings()'`, but these both dictionnaries are empty.

Comment: Please post the PDF.

Comment: The question is unclear. You list the keys of an annotation dictionary, but not its values. What do you mean when you say "the corresponding pure text"? Are you looking for the `/Contents` of the annotation? Or are you looking for the actual page content (in the page stream) defined by the `/QuadPoints`? Your question can't be answered in its current state. It should be closed as "unclear".

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all for your help ;)
Here is the (heavy but operating) answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

// PdfTextExtractor
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace PdfParsingiTextSharp {
```

Then a sample of code for a marker collection...

```
/*
 *  marker element, in order to build a collection
 */
public class cMark : IComparable {

    public enum TypeMarker{
        TypeSignet,
        TypeAnnotation
        };

    public enum TypeAnnotationSubType{
        TypeAnnotation_NONE,
        TypeAnnotation_UNDERLINE,
        TypeAnnotation_HIGHLIGHT,
        TypeAnnotation_STRIKEOUT,
        TypeAnnotation_SQUIGGLY
        };

    public TypeMarker eType;
    public TypeAnnotationSubType eAnnotationSubType;

    // level of signet
    public int signetLevel;
    // page in document
    public int pageNum;
    // indirect reference of page
    public int pageRef;
    // text of signet or annotation
    public String title;
    // area rectangle of annotation
    public iTextSharp.text.Rectangle annotRect;

    public cMark( TypeMarker p_eType, TypeAnnotationSubType p_TypeAnnotationSubType) {
        eType = p_eType;
        eAnnotationSubType = p_TypeAnnotationSubType;
        signetLevel = -1;
        pageNum = -1;
        pageRef = -1;
        title = "";
        annotRect = null;
        }

    /**
     * compare first on page, then on row, and finaly on column
     */
    public int CompareTo( object obj ) {
        cMarker compareObj = (cMarker)obj;
        int pageTest  = compareObj.pageNum.CompareTo(this.pageNum);
        if (pageTest != 0) {
            return pageTest;
            }
        else {
            if (annotRect == null) {
                return 0;
                }
            else {
                int rowTest  = compareObj.annotRect.Top.CompareTo( this.annotRect.Top);
                if (rowTest != 0) {
                    return rowTest;
                    }
                else {
                    return compareObj.annotRect.Left.CompareTo(this.annotRect.Left);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

An then parsing annotations.

```
// parsing annotation in document
    public static class Demo {

        /* Parse PDf file annotations
            */
        static void parseAnnotations( PdfReader reader, List<cMark> markers) {

            markers.Clear();

            // on each page
            for(int pg = 1; pg < reader.NumberOfPages+1; pg++) {

                PdfDictionary pagedic = reader.GetPageN( pg );
                // get annotations array
                PdfArray annotarray = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObject( pagedic.Get( PdfName.ANNOTS ) );
                // if no annotation ...
                if (annotarray == null || annotarray.Size == 0) {
                    continue;
                    }

                // on each annotation reference...
                foreach(PdfIndirectReference annot in annotarray.ArrayList) {

                    PdfDictionary annotationDic = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject( annot );

                    PdfName subType = (PdfName)annotationDic.Get( PdfName.SUBTYPE );

                    PdfString contents = annotationDic.GetAsString( PdfName.CONTENTS );

                    // if simple text...
                    if (    (contents != null) &&
                            (   (subType.Equals( PdfName.TEXT )) || 
                                (subType.Equals( PdfName.FREETEXT ))
                            ) 
                        ) {
                        String value = contents.ToString();

                        // single marker element 
                        cMark mrk = new cMark(cMark.TypeMarker.TypeAnnotation, cMark.TypeAnnotationSubType.TypeAnnotation_NONE);
                        mrk.pageNum = pg;
                        mrk.title = value;

                        if (annotationDic.Get( PdfName.RECT ) != null) {
                            PdfArray coord = annotationDic.GetAsArray( PdfName.RECT );
                            PdfRectangle textRect = new PdfRectangle( 
                                ((PdfNumber)coord[0]).FloatValue, 
                                ((PdfNumber)coord[1]).FloatValue, 
                                ((PdfNumber)coord[2]).FloatValue, 
                                ((PdfNumber)coord[3]).FloatValue);

                            mrk.annotRect = textRect.Rectangle;
                            }

                        markers.Add( mrk);
                        }

                    // if decorated text...
                    if (    (subType.Equals( PdfName.UNDERLINE )) || 
                            (subType.Equals( PdfName.HIGHLIGHT )) || 
                            (subType.Equals( PdfName.STRIKEOUT )) || 
                            (subType.Equals( PdfName.SQUIGGLY )) ) {

                        cMark mrk = new cMark(cMark.TypeMarker.TypeAnnotation, cMark.TypeAnnotationSubType.TypeAnnotation_NONE);
                        mrk.pageNum = pg;

                        if (subType.Equals( PdfName.UNDERLINE )) {
                            mrk.eAnnotationSubType = cMark.TypeAnnotationSubType.TypeAnnotation_UNDERLINE;
                            }
                        else if (subType.Equals( PdfName.HIGHLIGHT )) {
                            mrk.eAnnotationSubType = cMark.TypeAnnotationSubType.TypeAnnotation_HIGHLIGHT;
                            }
                        else if (subType.Equals( PdfName.STRIKEOUT )) {
                            mrk.eAnnotationSubType = cMark.TypeAnnotationSubType.TypeAnnotation_STRIKEOUT;
                            }
                        else if (subType.Equals( PdfName.SQUIGGLY )) {
                            mrk.eAnnotationSubType = cMark.TypeAnnotationSubType.TypeAnnotation_SQUIGGLY;
                            }

                        PdfObject pdfObjectQuad = annotationDic.Get( PdfName.QUADPOINTS );
                        if (pdfObjectQuad != null) {
                            PdfArray rect = annotationDic.GetAsArray( PdfName.QUADPOINTS );
                            // float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury
                            float lowX = Math.Min( ((PdfNumber)rect[0]).FloatValue, ((PdfNumber)rect[2]).FloatValue);
                            lowX = Math.Min( lowX, ((PdfNumber)rect[4]).FloatValue);
                            lowX = Math.Min( lowX, ((PdfNumber)rect[6]).FloatValue);

                            float lowY = Math.Min( ((PdfNumber)rect[1]).FloatValue, ((PdfNumber)rect[3]).FloatValue);
                            lowY = Math.Min( lowY, ((PdfNumber)rect[5]).FloatValue);
                            lowY = Math.Min( lowY, ((PdfNumber)rect[7]).FloatValue);

                            float upX = Math.Max( ((PdfNumber)rect[0]).FloatValue, ((PdfNumber)rect[2]).FloatValue);
                            upX = Math.Max( upX, ((PdfNumber)rect[4]).FloatValue);
                            upX = Math.Max( upX, ((PdfNumber)rect[6]).FloatValue);

                            float upY = Math.Max( ((PdfNumber)rect[1]).FloatValue, ((PdfNumber)rect[3]).FloatValue);
                            upY = Math.Max( upY, ((PdfNumber)rect[5]).FloatValue);
                            upY = Math.Max( upY, ((PdfNumber)rect[7]).FloatValue);

                            PdfRectangle textRect = new PdfRectangle( lowX, lowY, upX, upY);
                            RenderFilter[] filter = { new RegionTextRenderFilter(textRect.Rectangle) };
                            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy;
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
                                strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
                                sb.AppendLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy));
                                }
                            String result = sb.ToString();
                            mrk.title = result;
                            mrk.annotRect = textRect.Rectangle;
                            markers.Add( mrk);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```